# Xcode 4.5: Getting error "loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set"

Tags: xcode, loading, nib

After updating to Xcode 4.5 beta I have this error. I don't get the same error if I run the project by Xcode 4.3.3.

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "LocationList" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

"LocationList" is a custom cell and the owner is a subclass of UITableViewController. I tried to subclass it to UIViewController and connect it to "view" in IB but then it doesn't recognize `[self.tableview reloadData];`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using the beta until, it's well...out of beta :). Stick to 4.3.3, 4.5 is mostly for testing and reporting bugs.

Comment: I guess you are right. It messed up the other things, too and I switched back to 4.3.3.

Comment: OK, it's in GM seed and we are still seeing this. Now I wish someone had some answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and what I did was just overriding the loadView method. So weird new Xcode cannot figure that it is not supposed to load the TableView from the Nib when we override the UITableViewConroller (in my case I did not use IB to put a TableView, just created a new class which is a subclass of UITableViewController, this works fine in Xcode 3.3 but not in 4.5). 
This would definitely fix your issue,

```
-(void)loadView {
[super loadView];
```

}

but I am not so sure about the cause for this.

Comment: just found this from the iOS reference, this makes no sense to me by looking at this bug."You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property. The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. Your custom implementation of this method should not call super."