# View Outlet Is Not Set in StoryBoard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

What I Can Do With Exception

```
[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "TripDetailView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

Note : i Use StoryBoard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your story board file.
Select the `yellow colored option (viewController)` of `TripDetailView` and select the view outlet and drag it to the view.

[image: Main board]

Comment: i already make this and 
View Referencing Outlet is 
View --> TripDetailView  . 
and the same Exception When PresentModalViewController 
but when make PushViewNavigation No Exception but No Thing Happen

Comment: @TefaMohamed: please clean and run, still have issue ?

Comment: @TefaMohamed: some kind of weird bug, also check all outlets of the story board.

Comment: i build every thing dynamically else this view :S:S

Comment: @TefaMohamed: i didn't get your issue, but found a possible soultion in SO, hope it'll help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528254/xcode-4-5-getting-error-loaded-the-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set

Comment: Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really Really 
Thank You It Work 
Thank You Again Midhun MP :D:D

Comment: Can I Ask You Another Question . ?:D

Comment: My Application Is Based On TabBar and I PresentModalView In One Tab I Wanna Check If Tab Changed To Remove View fromSuberView 
how Can I Do it ?

Comment: @TefaMohamed: you can check by using `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;`. It'll return the currently selected segment index. And you can use this delegate method `- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` this delegate method will invoke when you change the tab bar selection.

Comment: First Sorry for more Question
I Use PresentModalView 
i wanna use PushViewController but when i use Self.navigation it equals null 
my app based in tabbar and inside one of TabBarControllers  i use table view i want to push view from cell of tableview . 
thanks in advance :$